# SIGABRT when presenting child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a content view, where I am trying to assign a child view controller to that content view.  My code works fine for iOS 6.0, but throws sigabrt for 5.0/5.1.  Here's the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  ContentWebViewController *initialContentVC = [[ContentWebViewController alloc] init];
  [self addChildViewController:initialContentVC];
  [initialContentVC.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];  // Throws SIGABRT here
  [self.containerView addSubview:initialContentVC.view];
  [initialContentVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  self.currentContentVC = initialContentVC;
}
```

What's going on here???

Comment: It is apparently caused by accessing the child's (initialContentVC) view property.  Still don't know why though...

Comment: Check if `initialContentVC.view` or `self.view` is nil at that point.

Comment: Checking throws the SIGABRT...No matter what I do to access the child view controller's view, it blows up SIGABRT.  But only in 5.0/5.1.  ios6.0 it runs fine... I don't get it.

Comment: Add separate NSLog statements for both these and see which line is crashing.

Comment: I did.  It crashes on accessing the child's view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode automatically checked "Use AutoLayout" in my nib file in IB.  That's why crashing on iOS earlier than 6.0.  Unchecking it did the trick.  This got me a few weeks ago too, how annoying!